# Assign another type to specific type

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have base class thats inherited by multiple classes

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public static Animal Get(int id)
    {
        return ...
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public CatPayload Payload { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public DogPayload Payload { get; set; }
}

public class CatPayload
{
    public int Lives { get; set; }
}

public class DogPayload
{
    public bool IsDangerous { get; set; }
}
```

I store only `Animal` identifier in the database, so when I'm getting it using static method I get instance of `Animal` and I can't get strongly-typed instance of `Payload`. What would be the best way to implement this? Only thing I currently have on mind is checking type of animal instance if it matches any of the subclasses, but I'm not sure if there some simpler way?

Comment: Are you saying that the Database code uses the classes that inherit from Animal, while other parts of the code use the Payload classes instead and you are not sure how to turn, eg Cat class into CatPayload?

Comment: No, I'm using SmartEnum classes instead of lookup database tables, so in database I don't have e.g. CatId as reference on some table but instead generic AnimalIdentifier which using my static class I can resolve (not the type itself but Name and Id). But now I have the need to also resolve the Payload type from Animal instance, since with Name/Id it was easy - they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your answer lacking a bit in details, so i don't know if this helps, but otherwise please extend your answer with more details, especially the parts of code that use these classes.

You can easily check with pattern matching:

```
// Creates a Cat, casts to an animal type
Animal myAnimal = new Cat(3);

if(myAnimal is Cat castedAnimalToCat)
{
   // myCat is Animal returned true, which means we have a cat object.
   // castedAnimalToCat is now a new variable of type Cat
   Console.WriteLine($"{castedAnimalToCat.CatPayload}");
}

if(myAnimal is Dog castedAnimalToDog)
{
  // ...
}
```

So somwhere in your database logic you can cast this to the right operand.
You can do some more fancier things with reflection, but your concern is always time safety and complexity with that.

Comment: This is exactly my initial idea, but I'm not sure if there is any "better" way - because I'd like the user to be somehow "forced" to add any additional pattern matching when new subclass is created (e.g. Lion), but it seems to me that isn't actually possible.

Comment: you can protect the application side by instead of a static public value that gets your database stuff you instead put a layer inbetween that does the casting

Answer (score 1):

1) Inheritance is supported in EF. This guide shows how it can be done:

[Tutorial: Implement Inheritance with EF in an ASP.NET MVC 5 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

2) You might also consider using a flat structure for your data model in which the entities are referencing each other with foreign keys:

```
public class Cat
{
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AccountId))]
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }

    public CatPayload Payload { get; set; }
}
```

3) For the payload you might use a string property for persistance containing json of the serialized class:

```
[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
CatPayload Payload { get; set; }

public string PayloadJson
{
    get => Payload == null ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Payload);
    set => Payload = value == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CatPayload>(value);
}
```